# iOS Toggles don't retain their state between view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, toggle

I have several toggles assigned to sounds. When switched on, a short clip plays for 30 seconds or so. Then when switching between viewcontrollers inside the app (eg, to the menu page) when i go back to the toggles they are all off! I would like them to retain their value after being switched on until the user decides to turn them off. This is not an issue until switching between pages inside the app.

Thanks for your help.

```
-(void)kickSwitchChanged:(UISwitch*)sw
{
    AppDelegate* app = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [app setKickStep:sw.tag state:sw.isOn];
}

-(void)snareSwitchChanged:(UISwitch*)sw
{
    AppDelegate* app = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [app setSnareStep:sw.tag state:sw.isOn];
}
```

Comment: You should have a strong reference to these objects in order to retain their state. Can you share some code?

Comment: Are you setting their on/off state in somewhere like `viewWillAppear` or similar? And is the view controller that houses them re-initialized when you return, or is it just recalled from somewhere in the nav stack (such as switching tabs on a tab controller or going back to it in a nav controller)

Comment: I have added some code, I'm not sure if the view contr. is re-initialized. Forgive me, I'm new to obj-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have sounds like a good use case for `NSUserDefaults`.

`NSUserDefaults` allows you to store data that will be persisted all the way through terminating and relaunching your app. It is meant to be used for "lighter-weight" data, like if a user wants a switch on or off.

Here is an example of saving a boolean default:

```
let kMySwitchDefaultKey = "isMySwitchOn"

NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(mySwitch.on, forKey: kMySwitchDefaultKey)
```

Here is an example of retrieving the same boolean default:

```
let wasMySwitchOn = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey(kMySwitchDefaultKey)
```

Typically you would set the default when the user changes the switch value, and you would get the default somewhere like `viewWillAppear` and use the saved value to update the switch state to be what it previously was set to.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html

## Edit

*I didn't see your Obj-C tag. Here is the same setting and getting code in Obj-C.*

### Setting

```
NSString* const kMySwitchDefaultKey = @"isMySwitchOn";
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:mySwitch.on forKey:kMySwitchDefaultKey];
```

### Getting

```
BOOL wasMySwitchOn = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:kMySwitchDefaultKey];
```